# Typescript / Type Safe Curried Functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, type-inference

How to safely type curried functions in typescript?
With particular regard to the following example

```ts
interface Prop {
    <T, K extends keyof T>(name: K, object: T): T[K];
    <K>(name: K): <T>(object: T) => /* ?? */;
}

const prop: Prop = (key, object) => object[key];

const valid1 = prop('foo', { foo: 'hello' }); // string
const valid = prop('foo')({ foo: 'hello' });  // string

// `never`, since `baz` does not exist in { foo: string }
const invalid = prop('baz')({ foo: 'hello' }); // never
```

Comment: Is this where you are suposed to implement the ["Type Guards"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) pattern....???

Answer (score 4):

#### [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)

```
function prop<T, K extends keyof T>(name: K, obj: T): T[K]
function prop<K extends PropertyKey>(name: K):
    <T extends Record<K, unknown>>(obj: T) => T[K]
function prop(name: any, obj?: any) { 
    if (obj === undefined) {
        return (obj: any) => obj[name]
    } else {
        return obj[name]
    }
}
// weak types used in impl for simplicity, as they don't matter for the caller.
// also this function body is not really complex
```

```
const valid1 = prop('foo', { foo: 'hello1' }); // string
const valid2 = prop('foo')({ foo: 'hello2' });  // string
const invalid = prop('baz')({ foo: 'hello' }); // compile error, `baz` not in { foo: string }
```

[Sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=44&pln=1&pc=1#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)

---

#### [function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types)

```
interface Prop {
    <T, K extends keyof T>(name: K, obj: T): T[K];
    <K extends PropertyKey>(name: K): <T extends Record<K, unknown>>(obj: T) => T[K]
}

const prop: Prop = (name: any, obj?: any) => {
    if (obj === undefined) {
        return (obj: any) => obj[name]
    } else {
        return obj[name]
    }
}
// weak types used here for simplicity like in first solution
```

```
const valid1 = prop('foo', { foo: 'hello1' }); // string
const valid2 = prop('foo')({ foo: 'hello2' });  // string
const invalid = prop('baz')({ foo: 'hello' }); // never
console.log(valid1, valid2) // hello1 hello2
```

[Sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAdkG8CwAUMicgDwAqANMgNLIQAekIAJgM7IDWEAnhjGQUAfAAoQcALYQAXHRoYARgCs5FAJRqA2rQC6AbiKly9Jiw5pMWaGF60+YidLm1N5Cg2YQ2nAEoQEDChWMloaAFcQLhAMAHcQYTElVSF1ZABeYSEdXSIAXyIiQJB2MGQsKzl0bAzkcSlZZDgQXgUVAH45Zt40zLwjUmBBUWSM9PTkSNYIGFAIVjSCYmNSKAgwcKgQOuSult6s5K0nCFzlkjyGABt2FCWV1fXN7aOTs+MCwk+Aem-kWIgcC4yFs1k44VurGQAAtoCgYEFkOxgJIsFdgAhgLZkOieMhQMhZlBSkiMFdwmBgBgQIVCMUSQA3ODo1gARlqFWwogA5AiMNyaLhCRgMHJubCrlcMKzucg8up9MhfkiwFBQABzIrUxnM4CsABMHKsPL53PUoiFfLFEql+tl8sVSr+pTVIE1dO1ZVATJZRq53MUcAAXmaLcLRchxRBJfy5QqncgQBAGdAtSUyRAAHRS9WiH161k0fMGtLKm3SmHR21AA)

*Note:* Function overloads and function types cannot be used completely interchangeably (more infos [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33482) or [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35338#issuecomment-558867975)). With latter, it may be necessary to annotate types with `any` in the function implementation part to account for incompatible return types in the defined call signatures - checkout this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=31&pln=7&pc=35#code/C4TwDgpgBAQlC8UDeBYAUFTUAUA7AhgLYQBcUAzsAE4CWuA5gJRkBGA9mwDYT64Dc6LDgLEylWg2ZRcAV0IsIVAWgC+6dAHoNUAO5U2DKFQjAZVXFFCQorDt17S2wKPnLka9Ai26W2Odlw8FgBk0nIKVIzoAMYGlFAsZHCIeESkFNR0TBoAVDa8IFA52vAAfJZUMhBAA) for an example.

Comment: I wouldn't really say that functions overloads are the `proper way`, since I'm not sure about having to use the `function` keyword or simply declaring a function multiple times. Can you point me where this is being stated? It really looks like both ways are perfectly equivalents.

Your first example gives compile errors since it would not accept any non `Record<K`.
Your second one declares `obj` as `undefined` which looks kind of wrong imo.

Comment: I agree with you, that statement is too sharply formulated (will change that). Motivation was, the function implementation part may produce compile errors in the second case, if return types of the call signatures are not compatible. So it is needed to weaken types with explicit `any` here (opposed to function overloads). In your particular case, that limitation doesn't get apparent though. PS: The compile error in the first example is intentional - you should not be able to choose a property, that does not exist in the object.

Comment: sharply again, "you should not be able to choose a property, that does not exist in the object." ...I need exactly that. Take a look at `R.prop` or `_.get`.

Comment: huh? Your `invalid` example in question indicates the opposite. If you really wanted to access a possibly not existent prop, you should return `undefined` instead of `never` and probably hint this behavior by naming the method `maybeProp`/`propOrUndefined` or allowing a default value to be set instead. In this case you can leave out the constraint. Usually a fail fast compile error is desirable with typed languages.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit verbose, 
but does what it needs to:

```js
interface Prop {
    <K extends PropertyKey, T extends {}>(name: K, object: T): K extends keyof T ? T[K] : undefined;
    <K extends PropertyKey>(name: K): <T extends {}>(object: T) => K extends keyof T ? T[K] : undefined;
}

declare const prop: Prop;

const invalid = prop('bar')({ foo: 'hello world' });
const valid = prop('foo')({ foo: 'hello world' });
const sLen = prop('length', 'Hello World');
const arity = prop('length')((a: number, b: number, c: number) => a + b + c);
```