# Typescript Typings for generic curry functions

Tags: typescript, generics, currying

I'm trying to get better with FP but struggling how to deal with typing generic "curry" functions.

For example, I've written a "Curry" version of reduce:

```js
const reduce = <S, R>(fn: (result: R, obj: S, i?: number, arr?: S[]) => R, init: R) => 
(objects: S[]) => 
objects.reduce(fn, init);

const numToSum: number[] = [1,2,3,5,8,13];

const result = reduce((sum, n) => sum + n, 0)(numToSum);
```

The problem is that typescript obviously can't know the type of `S` until you actually call the curry function with `numToSum`.

It's more obvious when you see it without the curry call:

```js
const sumNumbersFn = reduce((sum, n) => sum + n, 0);
```

In this case you can fix this by typing the arguments of the function itself with `n: number` or explicitly setting the generic parameters `<number[], number>`.

The former seems reasonable, but what I'm running into is that as things get more complex, I'm constantly having to provide generic signature.

**I'm wondering if I am missing something, and it is actually possible to get typescript to "infer" the types from the later function calls?**

Going back to the first example:

```js
const result = reduce((sum, n) => sum + n, 0)(numToSum);
```

It seems like the compiler actually SHOULD have all the information needed to infer types.

**Maybe my types are just off?**

### Update

Here's a more concrete/full example of the problem I'm running into

[TS-Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwCYFdgJgXhgHgMoA0MASgHwAUAZmAFwzmIQoA2UdxRIARgFZ2EwAlgH46YFAFsuCOEQCGcOKJh4A2gF0AlFlIkigsILYltmXQFgAUOW48EwKBH4bTFy7fuOAdIlToqYPqGUJoA3FZWoJCwEAjMnli4ACpEAmTkEABitPS2dEmuKoUBdDa8-IXEhQDeVjDwCFAocGC55TAFOjDUGdllPJphVgC%20EZZQAJ4ADhgAMgYIAJJQCBKJtZb1YHISCHTQcAYA5uGbMFOH6GKS0nCnw6djkzMwi2AAbiCC6Ot1Qkj7KCHMAnP7MBbLVZOGDzMBLFYSDT3R6WKLQGBMCTZRKxeIOcj9OhvT7fBCFWxecFwyESCCaBjINAIAmYoghLqYmAAahgUC8F1JRAADIMUWjYHAcZI%20tUYAB6OWSwQQGAoMAAazAIAA7mAvPUABJyd4YKAgc5wEDvQRIDCUFjMGBHBBwy4YwRHbZNRAwcAYuIJM1OxpCWBB7UgODqv42ugAcgAjHGCGCIQjoRoRkNLGMrEA)

Comment: I know that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60203078/typescript-type-safe-curried-functions is very similar (in title)... I think at it's core the question is different, but if you think this is a duplicate, my feelings won't be hurt

Comment: I'm also not sure that what I'm doing is even correct fp.  I wouldn't be surprised if what I've written above is a incorrect application

Comment: I don't think TS can ever infer the generic types from the value you eventually pass to the function returned - you could assign the return value of reduce and call it with multiple different values, for example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe if you have a moment, check out the ts-playground link I just added...  It probably does a better job of describing the problem I'm trying to overcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is to declare a function which you return from `select` function as generic:

```
function select<T, S>(sFn: (obj: T) => S) {
  function computation<G>(fn: (obj: S) => G) {
    return (obj: T) => fn(sFn(obj));
  }

  return computation;
}
```

---

P.S: I don't know why such kind of syntax doesn't work in TS playground:

```
const select = <T, S>(sFn: (obj: T) => S) => <G>(fn: (obj: S) => G) => {
  return (obj: T) => fn(sFn(obj));
}
```

Maybe because of some TS config settings. Thus I wrote the solution as a function declaration instead of a function expression.

Comment: ah man... I trashed so hard and was sooo close. I actually tried the "function expression" version along the way (probably multiple times).  

Your a hero!